# Spring ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am following a tutorial on spring, and so far my code allows you to add a user and view all users. I am now trying to include delete functionality. I added the below code to achieve this. I believe it is exactly as shown in the tutorial, but as a result I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. In the tutorial this error showed initially but upon refresh went away, but in my case it does not.

index.html

```
<a href="#" th:href="@{/user/delete/}+${user.id}">Delete</a>
```

userService.java

```
public void delete(User user) {userRepository.delete(user); }
```

userController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{user}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String delete(@PathVariable User user)
{
    String name = user.getFirstname()+" "+user.getLastname();
    userService.delete(user);
    return name;
}
```

application.properties (the bit added to this line is `;FILE_LOCK=FS`)

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./database.h2;FILE_LOCK=FS
```

I noticed in spring boot I now get the following, which I know references the lock method I just added for deleting, but not sure if this is why I am getting connection refused as the tutorial did the same thing but worked:

> 2018-01-24 16:18:54.446  WARN 6589 --- [  restartedMain]
>   o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain
>   connection to query metadata : Unsupported file lock method "FS "
>   [90060-196] 2018-01-24 16:18:54.447  WARN 6589 --- [  restartedMain]
>   ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered
>   during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested
>   service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] 2018-01-24
>   16:18:54.447  INFO 6589 --- [  restartedMain]
>   o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
>   2018-01-24 16:18:54.454  INFO 6589 --- [  restartedMain]
>   utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration
>   report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2018-01-24
>   16:18:54.459 ERROR 6589 --- [  restartedMain]
>   o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested
>   service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

UPDATE

Documentation for h2 database says this about file lock, so why would this be an unsupported method?:

> File Locking Method 'FS' This is the default mode for version 1.4 and
>   newer. This database file locking mechanism uses native file system
>   lock on the database file. No *.lock.db file is created in this case,
>   and no background thread is started. This mechanism may not work on
>   all systems as expected. Some systems allow to lock the same file
>   multiple times within the same virtual machine, and on some system
>   native file locking is not supported or files are not unlocked after a
>   power failure.
>
> To enable this feature, append ;FILE_LOCK=FS to the database URL.
>
> This feature is relatively new. When using it for production, please
>   ensure your system does in fact lock files as expected.

Comment: `Error creating bean with name` This is an application startup error. Your server hasn't started up. Try fixing this issue.

Comment: I added update to question. Thank you for your response. At least I know why it did not serve a page now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot application startup seems to be failed. Your sever is not started. As per the logs, creation of bean `entityManagerFactory` failed. This because, 
 `FS` is an `Unsupported file lock method`. Kindly check if this is valid and is what you need. Try removing this and check if it works.

Comment: I added update to question. Thank you for your response. At least I know why it did not serve a page now.

Comment: obvious question but, your h2 version?

Comment: It may be obvious question but I don't know how to check that. I set it up through intellij but have no real experience using it yet as I am just starting to find out more via tutorials.

Comment: do you have a `pom.xml` or a `.gradle` file in your project? if so check if there is an entry for h2, and if there is a version number along with that

Comment: I have a pom.xml file.  The only reference I see to h2 is:    `<groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
   <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>`

Comment: can you do a Ctrl+B after clicking on this piece of code and check for version in that file. alternatively in intellij, under Project pane, can you look for `External Libraries`. Can you try to find the jar file with h2 in the name and there will be version number along with that.. verify if its > 1.4 as per documentation

Comment: It is version 1.4.196

Comment: probably driver/hibernate version is old.. just check what happens if you leave out `FILE_LOCK=FS`. If you are working on tutorial, it may not be important..

Comment: It works if I leave it out. And I can now add and delete. The problem is that my existing user data was lost when I tried to add the code above. I will be submitting this work as an assignment so need to retain this data really. Not sure about the driver/hibernate thing but thank you for helping me with this.

Comment: sorry about that.. you can hard code to load some user data on application startup. review hibernate/spring/h2-driver versions and make sure all are current

Answer (score 0):

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./database.h2;FILE_LOCK=FS

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Just incase someone else encounters the same problem, adding the third line fixes this issue.