# Spring Boot application: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot

For a school project we are creating a Spring Boot application based on Restful. It works flawlessly locally, but once deployed to AWS I receive "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" on all GET and POST requests I send to my RestController.

If I just host my database on AWS it works fine locally, but as soon as I upload my project to an AWS instance it goes back to "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED". I get no exception in Java.

Does anyone have any idea about this? If so, I'd be more than grateful for the help.
I can of course show any code you need to see to clarify anything, I'm just unsure which code would be relevant.

Thanks a lot,
I hope you are all well.

Comment: This is a possible duplicate. Please refer to this question here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427589/spring-err-connection-refused

Comment: @SydneyMolobela It is not a duplicate. I have read that question. Or at least it didnt help me.

Comment: Try this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html

Comment: @xerx593 It is not a connection issue to the ec2-instance itself. I can acces the instance, I can access the website, but on my fetch/http requests receive the mentioned error

Comment: does the container startup (gracefully)?, is (ip+)"port"(=socket) accessible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I was running both front end and backend in the same project which resulted in API calls from the very same project to ip:8080 was void. I hosted the backend on ip:9090 and the frontend on ip:8080 in order for it to work.